# Increment value by 1 for every instance of a text value found within a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking to implement a formula which evaluates the values within a range to see if they contain the text from another table. For example

```
Table 1:
name: 3
Hello: 1
is: 3

Table 2:
Hello? My name is
What is your name...
Whose name is that
```

Apologies if this is a confusing format.

So with every instance of the text in table 1 that appears in table 2, the column will be incremented by 1. Is there a formula that can do this job for me?

Thanks

EDIT:

To be more specific for my problem, I am looking to count the occurrences of the strings in table 1:

```
com/iluwatar/object/pool/OliphauntPoolTest.java
com/iluwatar/tls/DateFormatCallableTestMultiThread.java
com/iluwatar/tls/App.java
com/iluwatar/servicelayer/common/DaoBaseImpl.java
```

As they are found in table 2:

```
87ee97a1,Tue Nov 7 07:37:12 2017 +0100,#114 Fixed checkstyle issue
 .../main/java/com/iluwatar/eip/aggregator/routes/AggregatorRoute.java    
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)

c45e9a1f,Tue Nov 7 07:24:31 2017 +0100,#114 Fixed checkstyle issue
 .../main/java/com/iluwatar/object/pool/OliphauntPoolTest.java
 1 file changed, 3 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)

89bfaf87,Tue Oct 31 17:32:11 2017 +0700,Fix typo
 converter/src/main/java/com/iluwatar/converter/Converter.java 
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

In this example, the count for com/iluwatar/object/pool/OliphauntPoolTest.java would be 1, as it was found once within the logged table 2, whereas the others would be 0.

Comment: i think what is confusing is how the comparison will be done and how you want to see the answer? As there are multiples items within each cell the easiest solution is looking for a complete match on the cell contents but if you are looking to match all strings within you need to determine what constitutes the start and end of a string e.g. is it Table or Table1 or Table1:, and how would you output the results?

Comment: So the output will just be the count total for each time that the string appears within table 2. As shown in the example, table 1 contains 3 words I'm looking to count... 'name' appears 3 times in the range of table 2, 'Hello' appears just once, and 'is' appears 3 times also. I've noticed that you could simply do =COUNTIF(A1:A3,"*name*"), but I'm actually looking to do something more like =COUNTIF(A1:A3,"*D1*") (and obviously that doesn't work) Does that make sense?

Comment: If you have a cell in table 2 where it is "Hello, Hello, Hello" ... it doesn't matter to my problem if it is only counted once. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Unfortunately that's exactly my problem - that doesn't work unless the strings in table 2 are complete matches to the cells in table 1. For example if a cell in table 2 was "name", it would count, but if the cell in table 2 was "name..." or "name of" - it doesn't count.

Comment: I think I would use a VBA solution but I don't know if that is a workable solution in your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following if you know will alway have the searched for string at the end

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(RIGHT($A$8:$A$18,LEN($A2))=$A2))
```

As @BarryHoudini mentions, and we discussed, you can use wildcard matches e.g. as given by Barry is

```
=COUNTIF(A$8:A$18,"*"&A2)
```

[image]

Consider adding Trim function to handle white space.

Comment: Excellent - many thanks, it works perfectly as far as I'm aware

Comment: Cool. Consider adding Trim  in if danger of white space

Comment: Couldn't you get the same result with `COUNTIF`, i.e. `=COUNTIF(A$8:A$18,"*"&A2)`

Comment: @barryhoudini We went through wildcard matches first and i don't know if i was being stupid tired but didn't get expected result so deleted the comments giving the match as you describe also edited out one of the wildcard answers and settled on this. I'll update it into the answer.